# improve code xml-mysql for large insert (86k entries) (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, xml, meekro

I must insert a large data to mysql from a xml every day, I do this job with cron job, but it takes about 2 hours to insert all the data to my DB,

Is there anyway to decrease that time?

Here is my code:

I use meekroDB to insert

My first code was (It is pretty simple):

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($xml->Table);$i++) {



DB::insert($PreFix."_stock", array(
  'refid' => (string)$xml->Table[$i]->refid,
  'articulo' => (string)$xml->Table[$i]->articulo,
  'modelo' => str_replace($lessCharMeta,$lessCharMeta2,(string)$xml->Table[$i]->modelo),
  'metadatos' => str_replace($lessCharMeta,$lessCharMeta2,(string)$xml->Table[$i]->metadatos),
  'estado' => (string)$xml->Table[$i]->estado,
  'reffab1' => (string)$xml->Table[$i]->reffab1,
  'reffab2' => (string)$xml->Table[$i]->reffab2,
  'refequiv' => (string)$xml->Table[$i]->refequiv,
  'nota' => str_replace($lessCharMeta,$lessCharMeta2,(string)$xml->Table[$i]->nota),
  'precio' => (string)$xml->Table[$i]->precio,
  'numfotos' => (string)$xml->Table[$i]->numfotos,
  'fechamod' => (string)$xml->Table[$i]->fechamod,
  'idarticulo' => (string)$xml->Table[$i]->idarticulo,
  'idversion' => (string)$xml->Table[$i]->idversion

    ));
```

So my question is: It is normal that long time to insert 86k rows or there is any best way?

Before i began testing with meekroDB I wrote this code, but i was getting always Timed out

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($xml->Table);$i++) {


        $VALUES[] = "( '".
        (string)$xml->Table[$i]->refid."' , '".
        (string)$xml->Table[$i]->articulo."' , '".
        str_replace($lessCharMeta,$lessCharMeta2,(string)$xml->Table[$i]->modelo)."' , '".
        str_replace($lessCharMeta,$lessCharMeta2,(string)$xml->Table[$i]->metadatos)."' , '".
        (string)$xml->Table[$i]->estado."' , '".
        (string)$xml->Table[$i]->reffab1."' , '".
        (string)$xml->Table[$i]->reffab2."' , '".
        (string)$xml->Table[$i]->refequiv."' , '".
        str_replace($lessCharMeta,$lessCharMeta2,(string)$xml->Table[$i]->nota)."' , '".
        (string)$xml->Table[$i]->precio."' , '".
        (string)$xml->Table[$i]->numfotos."' , '".
        (string)$xml->Table[$i]->fechamod."' , '".
        (string)$xml->Table[$i]->idarticulo."' , '".
        (string)$xml->Table[$i]->idversion."' )";

     }


    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$PreFix."_stock(ID int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `refid` VARCHAR(10),
    `articulo` VARCHAR(200),
    `modelo` VARCHAR(16),
    `metadatos` VARCHAR(500),
    `estado` VARCHAR(100),
    `reffab1` VARCHAR(50),
    `reffab2` VARCHAR(50),
    `refequiv` VARCHAR(50),
    `nota` VARCHAR(200),
    `precio` VARCHAR(15),
    `numfotos` VARCHAR(2),
    `fechamod` VARCHAR(50),
    `idarticulo` VARCHAR(10),
    `idversion` VARCHAR(10) )"
    );
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();



$temp = "";

foreach ($VALUES as $KEY){

if (!empty($KEY)){
$temp = $temp."  , ".$KEY;}

}


    $sentencia = "
    INSERT INTO ".$PreFix."_stock
    (refid,articulo,modelo,metadatos,estado,reffab1,reffab2,refequiv,nota,precio,numfotos,fechamod,idarticulo,idversion)
     VALUES 
    ";



    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sentencia.$temp) ){
       $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else {

        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error."<hr/>");
    }
```

Then I decided to jump to the same script over and over every 500 insert by sending the for loop index by post data, but when I set cron job to do the work it was never jumping over the script.

With meekroDB its a bit slow but I never get PHP timed out

Comment: Doing 86,000 inserts has never taken me that long.  Probably closer to a minute or a few minutes.  I have a cron job that runs through 150,000 per day and it takes around 30 seconds.  Could have a lot to do with your server hardware and setup too

Comment: Can you show us a piece of your XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has also a [`LOAD XML INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html).
According to the provided XML, I think it needs to be something like this:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'data.xml'
INTO TABLE tablename
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Table>'
```

If this do not work, you could try to convert it to a CSV format and use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) instead.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE tablename
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Just remembering that to make `LOAD ... LOCAL INFILE` to work you need to have your `data.xml` or `data.csv` file in the same server as MySQL and use the real path to the file.

You could also import the file to a temp table to do some processing before inserting it into the real table:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT tmp.col1, tmp.col2, replace(tmp.col3, 'foo', 'bar')
FROM tmp WHERE tmp.col1 > 0
```

Hope it works! :)

Comment: Thanks this helped me,
I couldnt do it through XML because my mysql version is 5.1 ( I read that till 5.2 wasnt implemented LOAD XML INFILE), so i parse the data to CSV.
I had another little problem, but it was solved, mysql by defaut has LOAD IN FILE deactivated I had to activate that from mysql config.

It takes about 5min to dump the data to mysql, so it is solved.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as a batch job.
Dont do a insert after every read. Insert multiple rows at a time.

What you would do, is you gather like 10 rows inside array, then build query from these rows
like:
INSERT INTO table (field 1,2,3,4,4 etc..) VALUES (dataset1), (dataset2), (dataset3)... 10

Then you will save a LOT of time, because u do 10x less inserts. You probably have MANY rows in your database... and maybe even multiple indexes, which makes inserts slow.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql documentation:
"When loading a table from a text file, use LOAD DATA INFILE. This is usually 20 times faster than using INSERT statements"

I think I will parse the data from xml to csv then use load data.

part of xml file -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <referencia>001004024053008</referencia>
    <ubicacion>Montada revisada</ubicacion>
    <refid>3301474</refid>
    <articulo>MOTOR COMPLETO</articulo>
    <modelo>FORD MONDEO TURNIER (GE) Futura X   |   01.06 - 12.07</modelo>
    <metadatos> | MOTOR COMPLETO | FORD MONDEO TURNIER (GE) FUTURA X 2.0 TDCI CAT |   2007 08825 |  | 3301474 |  |  | COLECTOR DE ADMISION DESMONTADO</metadatos>
    <estado>Material revisado</estado>
    <reffab1 />
    <reffab2 />
    <refequiv />
    <nota>COLECTOR DE ADMISION DESMONTADO</nota>
    <precio>900.000</precio>
    <numfotos>0</numfotos>
    <fechamod>2014-08-13T19:38:39.52+02:00</fechamod>
    <idarticulo>9</idarticulo>
    <idversion>2216764</idversion>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <referencia>006001083046004</referencia>
    <ubicacion>Montada revisada</ubicacion>
    <refid>3300752</refid>
    <articulo>CAJA CAMBIOS</articulo>
    <modelo>VOLKSWAGEN LUPO (6X1/6E1) Advance   |   06.04 - 12.05</modelo>
    <metadatos> | CAJA CAMBIOS | VOLKSWAGEN LUPO (6X1/6E1) ADVANCE 1.4 TDI | AMF  2001 08822 |  | 3300752 |  |  | </metadatos>
    <estado>Material revisado</estado>
    <reffab1 />
    <reffab2 />
    <refequiv />
    <nota />
    <precio>300.000</precio>
    <numfotos>0</numfotos>
    <fechamod>2014-08-13T19:30:43.922+02:00</fechamod>
    <idarticulo>175</idarticulo>
    <idversion>2216763</idversion>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <referencia>001004083046004</referencia>
    <ubicacion>Montada revisada</ubicacion>
    <refid>3300716</refid>
    <articulo>MOTOR COMPLETO</articulo>
    <modelo>VOLKSWAGEN LUPO (6X1/6E1) Advance   |   06.04 - 12.05</modelo>
    <metadatos> | MOTOR COMPLETO | VOLKSWAGEN LUPO (6X1/6E1) ADVANCE 1.4 TDI | AMF  2001 08822 | AMF | 3300716 |  |  | </metadatos>
    <estado>Material revisado</estado>
    <reffab1>AMF</reffab1>
    <reffab2 />
    <refequiv />
    <nota />
    <precio>1000.000</precio>
    <numfotos>0</numfotos>
    <fechamod>2014-08-13T19:30:46.792+02:00</fechamod>
    <idarticulo>9</idarticulo>
    <idversion>2216763</idversion>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <referencia>010015023127001</referencia>
    <ubicacion>Almacenada</ubicacion>
    <refid>2851404</refid>
    <articulo>AIRBAG DELANTERO IZQUIERDO</articulo>
    <modelo>FIAT SCUDO ACRISTALADO    |   01.07 - ...</modelo>
    <metadatos> | AIRBAG DELANTERO IZQUIERDO | FIAT SCUDO ACRISTALADO 2.0 JTD | RHK  2007 07282 |  | 2851404 |  |  | [V.A] FIAT SCUDO 2.0 HDI FURGON - ACRISTALADO - CORTO [07282]</metadatos>
    <estado>Material revisado</estado>
    <reffab1 />
    <reffab2 />
    <refequiv />
    <nota>[V.A] FIAT SCUDO 2.0 HDI FURGON - ACRISTALADO - CORTO
[07282]</nota>
    <precio>0.000</precio>
    <numfotos>3</numfotos>
    <fechamod>2013-06-12T21:47:33+02:00</fechamod>
    <idarticulo>54</idarticulo>
    <idversion>2207294</idversion>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <referencia>010071023113007</referencia>
    <ubicacion>Almacenada</ubicacion>
    <refid>3021150</refid>
    <articulo>AIRBAG CORTINA DELANTERO IZQUIERDO</articulo>
    <modelo>FIAT STILO (192) 1.9 120 Dynamic Multijet   |   09.05 - ...</modelo>
    <metadatos> | AIRBAG CORTINA DELANTERO IZQUIERDO | FIAT STILO (192) 1.9 120 DYNAMIC MULTIJET 1.9 8V JTD CAT |   0 |  | 3021150 |  |  | </metadatos>
    <estado>Material de segunda mano</estado>
    <reffab1 />
    <reffab2 />
    <refequiv />
    <nota />
    <precio>0.000</precio>
    <numfotos>0</numfotos>
    <fechamod>2013-06-12T23:22:17+02:00</fechamod>
    <idarticulo>460</idarticulo>
    <idversion>2208730</idversion>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <referencia>010080059055011</referencia>
    <ubicacion>Almacenada</ubicacion>
    <refid>3104859</refid>
    <articulo>PRETENSOR AIRBAG IZQUIERDO</articulo>
    <modelo>NISSAN PRIMERA BERLINA (P11) SLX   |   05.96 - 12.99</modelo>
    <metadatos> | PRETENSOR AIRBAG IZQUIERDO | NISSAN PRIMERA BERLINA (P11) SLX 2.0 TURBODIESEL CAT | CD20T  1998 07690 |  | 3104859 |  |  | </metadatos>
    <estado>Material de segunda mano</estado>
    <reffab1 />
    <reffab2 />
    <refequiv />
    <nota />
    <precio>0.000</precio>
    <numfotos>4</numfotos>
    <fechamod>2013-08-12T09:32:57+02:00</fechamod>
    <idarticulo>469</idarticulo>
    <idversion>2210365</idversion>
  </Table>
```